# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ - why does cardinality matter?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, proof-writing

When I look up why  $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are not homeomorphic, almost all the answers just say something along the line of "Because, Cardinality" and then ends there.

Can someone provides the reason or the proof as to why cardinality would matter?

Comment: A homeomorphism is a continuous bijection whose inverse is continuous. In particular, it is a bijection. You may know that a bijection preserves cardinality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A homeomorphism by definition is a bicontinous BIJECTION. Meaning they must have the same cardinalities. $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ while $\mathbb{Q}$ has cardinality $\aleph_0<2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ does not provably have cardinality $\aleph_1$. It has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, which _may_ be $\aleph_1$ (that is, the Continuum Hypothesis holds), but is _could_ also be $\aleph_{100}$, or $\aleph_{\omega_1}$, or virtually any other aleph. Cantor's Theorem shows that $\aleph_0 < 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.